# Why do directly-inserted labels in pspicture displace other following objects?

Tags: pstricks

```
\documentclass[border=15pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,algebraic](-7,-1)(7,7)
% \uput[90](1,3){ $\sqrt{40-x^2}$} % Line 1
% $\sqrt{40-x^2}$ % Line 2
\psplot[plotpoints=500]{ 40 sqrt neg}{40 sqrt}{sqrt(40-x^2)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

With Line 1, I get:

[image]

With Line 2, I get:

[image]

I think the semicircle in the second case should be placed at the same coordinate as the first case.

Comment: I think that in the second case, `$\sqrt{40-x^2}$` is not a pstricks command, whichdoes not know what to do with this stuff, so it `\rput`s it at the origin. This being said, do you really need `\psplot` to draw a half-circle?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, it is not a pstricks command, but it _belong to_ pstricks environment, I think so!

Comment: Gangsters and wild animals are not your family members, they come into your house and  you want everything just fine as usual. I think so!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The presence of illegal objects in `pspicture` will make legal objects that follow get distorted.

The  left picture demonstrates a case  when there is no illegal object. The legal object (a dot) that follows is placed exactly at `(2,2)` as expected. But the right picture shows the opposite, the dot gets displaced to the right because of the presence of illegal object.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,-1)(3,3)
    %illegal-objects
    \pscircle*(2,2){2pt}
\end{pspicture}
\quad
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,-1)(3,3)
    illegal-objects
    \pscircle*(2,2){2pt}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

## Edit

Or you can use `%` to disable the `illegal-objects`, duplicate the `illegal-objects`, and wrap it with `\rlap` as follows.

```
\documentclass[border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,-1)(3,3)
    % illegal-objects
    \rlap{illegal-objects}
    \pscircle*(2,2){2pt}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Best, thank for your answer, I think what you say are true.

Answer (score 2):

Use a box of zero width:  `\makebox[0pt]{$\sqrt{40-x^2}$}% Line 2`