# How to delete unnecessary white space?

Tags: pstricks

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,arrowinset=0](0,-1)(4,2)
\begin{psmatrix}[colsep=.5cm,rowsep=1.2cm]
& [name=A]\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$M_{0,4} \times \mathbb{P}^1 $\\
[name=B]$B$ & [name=C]\,\,\,\,\,\,$M_{0,4}$
\end{psmatrix}
\pcline[nodesep=.3]{->}(B)(C)       \nbput{$\kappa$}
\pcline[nodesep=.3]{->}(A)(C)       \nbput[labelsep=.1]{$\pi$}
\naput{\foreach \i in {0.1,0.25,0.4,0.55}{%
    \pcline{->}(\i,-.4)(\i,.45)} \nbput[labelsep=.1]{$\sigma_i$}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

After see all the answers, done :)

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{psmatrix}[colsep=.5cm,rowsep=1.2cm]
& [name=A]\qquad $M_{0,4} \times \mathbb{P}^1 $\\
[name=B]$B$ & [name=C] \quad $M_{0,4}$
\end{psmatrix}
\psset{arrowinset=0}
\pcline[nodesep=.3]{->}(B)(C)       \nbput{$\kappa$}
\pcline[nodesep=.3]{->}(A)(C)       \nbput[labelsep=.1]{$\pi$}
\naput{\foreach \i in {0.1,0.25,0.4,0.55}{%
    \pcline{->}(\i,-.4)(\i,.45)} \nbput[labelsep=.1]{$\sigma_i$}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Although you've received answers that seem to solve your problem, I have no clue what your question is. For the benefit of future users of the site, could you please add a textual description of what your problem is and what you're trying to achieve? That way, people with similar problems will be able to find your question and its answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put the matrix somewhere, e.g. using `\rput`. This is the way to nest `pspicture`s.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,arrowinset=0](-.5,-1)(4,2)
\rput[bl](0,0){\begin{psmatrix}[colsep=.5cm,rowsep=1.2cm]
& [name=A]\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$M_{0,4} \times \mathbb{P}^1 $\\
[name=B]$B$ & [name=C]\,\,\,\,\,\,$M_{0,4}$
\end{psmatrix}}
\pcline[nodesep=.3]{->}(B)(C)       \nbput{$\kappa$}
\pcline[nodesep=.3]{->}(A)(C)       \nbput[labelsep=.1]{$\pi$}
\naput{\foreach \i in {0.1,0.25,0.4,0.55}{%
    \pcline{->}(\i,-.4)(\i,.45)} \nbput[labelsep=.1]{$\sigma_i$}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you make the picture smaller, it will become smaller.

```
  \begin{pspicture}[showgrid,arrowinset=0](-.5,-0.3)(3,2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It makes no sense to use the `pspicture` envorimnent in this case:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{psmatrix}[colsep=.5cm,rowsep=1.2cm]
& [name=A]\qquad$M_{0,4} \times \mathbb{P}^1 $\\
[name=B]$B$ & [name=C]\quad$M_{0,4}$
\end{psmatrix}
\pcline[nodesep=.3]{->}(B)(C)       \nbput{$\kappa$}
\pcline[nodesep=.3]{->}(A)(C)       \nbput[labelsep=.1]{$\pi$}
\naput{\foreach \i in {0.1,0.25,0.4,0.55}{%
    \pcline{->}(\i,-.4)(\i,.45)} \nbput[labelsep=.1]{$\sigma_i$}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really need the grid, then write the `\psmatrix`, which
is internally nothing else than an `array`, into a box of zero width:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,arrowinset=0](0,-1)(4,2) 
\makebox[0pt][l]{%
\begin{psmatrix}[colsep=.5cm,rowsep=1.2cm]
    & [name=A]\qquad$M_{0,4} \times \mathbb{P}^1 $\\
    [name=B]$B$ & [name=C]\quad$M_{0,4}$
\end{psmatrix}}
\pcline[nodesep=.3]{->}(B)(C)       \nbput{$\kappa$}
\pcline[nodesep=.3]{->}(A)(C)       \nbput[labelsep=.1]{$\pi$}
\naput{\foreach \i in {0.1,0.25,0.4,0.55}{%
    \pcline{->}(\i,-.4)(\i,.45)} \nbput[labelsep=.1]{$\sigma_i$}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`\makebox` does the same as `\rput`. It is the same behaviour as mentioned in your question [Why do directly-inserted labels in pspicture displace other following objects?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493191/why-do-directly-inserted-labels-in-pspicture-displace-other-following-objects)
The `array` (`\psmatrix`)  has a width and that's the reason why the old coordinate system is shifted to the right and you get the whitespace.  Real PSTricks objects have *no* width. However, `\psmatrix`  should not be inside `pspicture`.